# Pandas str.contains not giving valid result when string ends with .(dot) along with boundryline

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column value with `.` at the end say `New York .`. when I try to search for the same with boundary line (`\b`) it gives an invalid result.

Please find below code snippet.

```
# importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

# importing re for regular expressions
import re

# Creating the Series
sr = pd.Series(['The New York . City'])

# Creating the index
idx = ['City 1']

# set the index
sr.index = idx

# Print the series
print(sr)


# find if 'is' substring is present
result = sr.str.contains(pat = '\\bNew York \\.\\b')

# print the result
print(result)
```

**Expected Result:**

```
City 1    The New York . City
dtype: object
City 1    True
```

**Actual Result:**

```
City 1    The New York . City
dtype: object
City 1    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Why do you use a double backslash?

Comment: `.` is a special character in a regular expression. To match an actual period, escape it.

Comment: Why does your code contain `'New York .'`, but your output  `The New York . City`?

Comment: Even after escaping `.`  also it didn.t work.

Comment: Have updated the code in question with minor change in input string.

Comment: Again: why do you use a double backslash. Don't. You're just (and only) escaping the backslash.

Comment: Even with a single backslash, it's the same result

Comment: Note that `\b` is defined as "Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of word characters.". See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html. A single period is not a sequence of word characters, so `\.\b` wouldn't match.

Comment: Try with `r'\bNew York \.'` (not `\b` at the end, as per my previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
result = sr.str.contains(pat = '\\bNew York \\.')
```

without the final `\\b`. As [the documentation states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> \b
>
> ```
> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that
> ```
>
> formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W
> character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the
> string.

Since a period is not a word character, using `\\b` after a period will not match. If you need to ensure there is whitespace after the single dot, add a `\\s` instead.

---

For your sanity, use raw strings, that saves you from double escapes:

```
result = sr.str.contains(pat = r'\bNew York \.')
```

(Note the `r` prefix in front of the string. Again, see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#raw-string-notation).)